# Use variable for full path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

For example, I have:

1) **text.txt** file in **D:\Test** folder

2) **text.txt** file in **D:\x64_this-is-my-test_54321_99.88.77.555_folder_n12345** folder

How can I copy with replacement (xcopy /o /y)

**text.txt** file from **Test** folder to the **x64_this-is-my-test_54321_99.88.77.555_folder_n12345** folder

by using command line (FOR /R [[drive:]path] %%parameter IN (set) DO command )

if I know only that the second folder name starts  with **x64_this-is-my-test**, and the other part of the folder's name is unknown?

Comment: Have you tried using wildcard for the destination? `x64_this-is-my-test*`

Comment: Yes I tried using command:
**xcopy D:\Test\text.txt "D:\x64_this-is-my-test*\text.txt" /o /y**
And it's not working.

Comment: Seems this link has some relevant info - check it out once - http://www.sevenforums.com/backup-restore/270966-how-copy-folders-using-wildcards-2.html?s=3dddd27fbbcf030bb071190ae61bbd7e

Comment: Thanks, but it's a little bit different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /d %%# in ("D:\x64_this-is-my-test*") do copy /y "D:\Test\text.txt" "%%~f#\test.txt"
```

using xcopy for single files is bad idea .Better use copy.

Comment: Thank you! Your command is that what I need.
**xcopy** has very nice parameter **/o**

little change your solution:

**for /d %%f in ("D:\x64_this-is-my-test*") do xcopy /o /y "D:\Test\text.txt" "%%f"**

Comment: @VldGrdv  to change file permissions you can use CACLS command

Comment: yes, I know. 
But change file(folder) permissions and user to VldGrdv, then back to Admin use more commands. For me, better to copy with permissions (xcopy /o).

Comment: @VldGrdv - here's a trick how xcopy can be used for a single file - but is language dependent `echo F| XCOPY C:\utils\MyFile.txt D:\Backup\CopyFile.txt`

Comment: Imho, this trick is more useful for text files?!
But I also need to copy image files and programs, where the owner is TrustedInstaller. In the first question I use txt-file, just for example.